# Office365/AZUR get token before authenticatedrequest

Tags: office365, office365api, office365-apps

How can I get this token without going through this process:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/create-web-apps-using-cors-to-access-files-in-office-365
"Using implicit grant, your application requests an access token from Azure AD for the currently signed-in user by sending the user to an authorization URL where the user signs in with their Office 365 credentials and then is redirected back to the app with the access token in the URL."

All I want is making a simple GET/POST request whatever type of authentication is needed. I can't follow the steps above since we're using a single page application.

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something simple, so if anyone already experience this problem any hint would be very welcomed!

Answer (score 0):

An access token is required for querying Office 365 API. You could use an implicit authentication flow to get access token , you need to update the application's manifest to allow the OAuth implicit grant flow because it is not allowed by default:

1.Select the Configure tab of your application's entry in the Azure Management Portal.

2.Using the Manage Manifest button in the drawer, download the manifest file for the application and save it to your computer.

3.Open the manifest file with a text editor. Search for the 
oauth2AllowImplicitFlow property. By default it is set to false; change it to true and save the file.

4.Using the Manage Manifest button, upload the updated manifest file.

You could check out all these specific samples(SPA Application using OAuth implicit grant flow) on GitHub:

- [SinglePageApp-jQuery-DotNet](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-javascript-singlepageapp-dotnet-webapi)
- [SinglePageApp-AngularJS-DotNet](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-angularjs-singlepageapp)